# How can I use __gcov_flush to flush all buffers?

Tags: flush, xcode4.6, llvm-clang

How can i use __gcov_flush?
In my app I catch the uncaughtException and in my handler __gcov_flush function was called.i want to flush all .gcda files (coverage file),but only the file i call __gcov_flush was flushed?  someone said that is a bug(http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15191) ,but what should I do to flush all the buffers?